# wpf imagesource bad trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I want to create a data trigger in pure xaml (as in, no events or convertors or any bhind code), that will trigger if an image source doesn't have an image.
For example I have an image browser and image preview, and I want to do something if the the browser selected a file that isn't an image.

Comment: also forgot to add that i'm using ImageBrush.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory using Data Trigger ?
Can't you just set de Property Trigger in style ?

Something like :

```
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="Source" Value="">
  Something here...
</Trigger>
```

Tell me if it's not the behaviour you expect

Comment: As per OP query, the image source is not empty everytime

Comment: I'm interesting on how he's currently binding the source of the preview image with the selected file...

Comment: I am using style triggers, and as for the binding : ImageSource="{Binding elementname=txtImagePath, path=text}"

Comment: If you want more detail, the thing I want to set when that trigger happens is the visability of the border that contains the image so it isn't collapses when there isn't an image to present.